# Flash loads xml differently on Windows and Mac

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am loading an xml file using AS2.0. On Mac, all the elements load completely, but as soon as I run it on Windows, only the first element of type `item` loads. When I run it on Mac, the elements are loaded in and all `item`'s are separate buttons. When I run it on Windows, only one button appears and its name is ch1. Virgin Group Holdings. None of the other `item` elements load. I don't have a Windows versions of Flash to work on, so I cannot debug.

Is there another way to determine if this has to do with the XML file loading incompletely or with the depths of the Movieclips? Here is the [URL](http://toolboxstudio.co.za/virleo2/virleo_new.html)

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
    <item link="vgh" name="ch1. Virgin Group Holdings" movie="VirleoGH">
        <menuitem link="vgh_overview">Group Overview</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="vgh_capacity">Group Capacity</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="vgh_archive">Certification Archive</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="vgh_timeline">Timeline</menuitem>
    </item>
    <item link="mdb" name="ch2. Manny Design Bureau" movie="MechanologyDB">
        <menuitem link="mdb_overview">Overview</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="mdb_archive">Works Archive</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="mdb_showroom">Showroom</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="mdb_skills">Core Skills</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="mdb_products">Products</menuitem>
    </item>
    <item link="sai" name="ch3. Special Autonomic Industries" movie="SpecialAI">
        <menuitem link="sai_overview">Overview</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="sai_archive">Works Archive</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="sai_showroom">Showroom</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="sai_skills">Core Skills & Serices</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="sai_products">Products</menuitem>
        <menuitem link="sai_infrastructure">Infrastructure</menuitem>
    </item>
    <item link="iacs" name="ch4. Interesting And Cool Stuff"></item>
</menu>
```

And here is the code where I load the XML file:

```
var xmlFile:String = "menu.xml";
var menu:XML = new XML();
// ignores spaces and declaration in XML file, improves parsing of XML file
menu.ignoreWhite = true;

// create 'mainMenu' (type Menu), holds all functions related to menu and constructs array from XML
var mainMenu:Menu = new Menu();

// event handler triggerred when XML is completely loaded
menu.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {

    if (success) {
        // passes XML file to buildMenu function in Menu class to build menu Array
        mainMenu.buildMenu(this);
        // passes 'mainMenu' (type Menu) to buildScene function, builds whole scene with individual MC's
        buildScene(mainMenu);

        // set depth of navigation to top of pile, in order for buttons to move behind the navigation, instead of on top of it
        _root.navigation.swapDepths(theScene);
    }
}

// load XML file
menu.load(xmlFile);
```

Does somebody mind giving me pointers on pitfalls that I missed?

Regards & TIA

// EDIT src for buildMenu() function

```
// build multi-dimensional array from XML file received
    function buildMenu(menu:XML):Void {

        // determine how many chambers there are now
        menuArray = menu.firstChild.childNodes;
        var length:Number = menuArray.length;

        // dynamic according to number of chambers
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var sublength:Number = menuArray[i].childNodes.length;
            var submenu:Array = new Array();

            // chamber name and link
            var xmlNode:XMLNode = menuArray[i];
            submenu["name"] = xmlNode.attributes.name;
            submenu["link"] = xmlNode.attributes.link;
            submenu["movie"] = xmlNode.attributes.movie;

            trace(submenu["name"]);

            // create sub-item for each chamber
            for (var j:Number = 0; j < sublength; j++) {
                var subXmlNode:XMLNode = xmlNode.childNodes[j];

                var item:Array = new Array(subXmlNode.firstChild, subXmlNode.attributes.link);
                submenu.push(item);
            }

            // create an entry for each chamber
            mainmenu.push(submenu);
        }
    }
```

// EDIT 2

I am now running this file from a remote server (Linux box), but still only the first  element loads on Windows, with no siblings. On Mac, everything loads fine, I am at a dead end, my deadline (draft #2) for this is in about 12hours and I still need to get a night's rest in. Does anyone have the slightest inkling what this could be? Any pointers or advice will be cordially accepted. The [url](http://toolboxstudio.co.za/virleo2/virleo_new.html)

Regards and TIA.

// EDIT 3

I am now debugging in Windows and have found that the XML file does get loaded completely eventually. What is odd is that I trace the `_x` and `_y` values of all the movieclips, and all change constantly to an acceptable value, but still only the first-added movieclip is visible on the stage. I have traced their depths which do in fact differ, they are enabled (traced), they are `_visible` (traced that also), everything works perfect on Mac, except when I run it on Windows, so clearly, Flash Player in Windows in doing something unexpected, has anybody encountered this before?

I would really appreciate some help.

Regards and TIA.

Comment: Please provide the source code for mainMenu.buildMenu(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the cause of your problem but two things to look out for in the XML is that the & in "Core Skills & Services" makes the XML invalid. Flash is pretty forgiving about such things but a stricter parser would report it as an error. For example Firefox won't display that XML, and report a "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed" with reference to the position of the &. Trying to open the XML file in Firefox (or IE) is often a quick way to discover errors in XML that Flash/AS2 won't report.

So to use a & in a text, the text needs to be marked as CDATA for it to be valid XML:

```
<menuitem link="sai_skills"><![CDATA[Core Skills & Services]]></menuitem>
```

Another thing to look out for (again, it may not be the cause of your problem) is to make sure the file is actually saved in UTF-8 format. Having encoding="UTF-8" in the XML itself is not enough, the file also needs to be saved as UTF-8. This is a quite usual mistake, but as you say you use Dreamweaver, I would assume Dreamweaver normally takes care of that aspect.

Comment: Oh, yes, well I changed that to Core Skills and Services. Also, I did check Dreamweaver and the Prefs state that is supposed to save all new files as Unicode 5.0 UTF-8. I am now running this on a Linux server remotely, but still Windows computers only show the first element "ch1. Virleo Group Holdings". I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

What editor do you use for XML file ?
Windows and Mac have a diffrent line ending chars.

Comment: I use Dreamweaver CS4 and as far as I know the line end chars are set to Windows format.

Comment: Do you know of a short method to correct any wrong line end chars?

Comment: Well, I edited the file on a Windows computer in Dreamweaver CS3 now, I deleted all newlines and manually put them back in. Still, Flash only loads one element, but not the rest of the siblings.

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
menu.ignoreWhite = false;
```

Windows uses CR+LF to mark a newline, Mac uses LF

Comment: I can't, that will completely throw off my parsing.

Comment: Are you parsing xml yourself? why don't you use API methods?

Comment: Sorry, it's the only way I'm used to. What API's do you recommend?

Comment: ``ignoreWhite`` only ignored _insignificant_ whitespace (ie. the whitespace between the end of one tag and the start of another). It is unlikely to cause you problems if you turn it on.

Comment: Well, I did try and then it just loaded nothing, both Mac and Windows.

Comment: The standard xml class in actionscript